# Make a Android Jar?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making a program that is going to utilize some of Androids coding in my Java project, but to use it I need an Android Jar file.  How do I make a Android Jar for use in Eclipse?

Comment: you need to install android SDK. did you already do that?

Comment: you don't need to import android jar.only install Android SDK and add path to it.

Comment: I'm curious: What android specific features do you want to use in a non-Android project? Maybe you find those in the JDK...

Comment: @user714965 I need to get the wifi abilities like wifiScan

Comment: I would guess this is pretty much hardware dependent and will only run on an android device.

Answer (score 0):

you will find the android.jar file inside this folder **android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-21** if you have already installed Android SDK but i don't know if it can be used directly as a jar in eclipse projects.